# Remove duplicate rows by date

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to remove duplicate rows in column `AUTHORS_CONVERSATION`.

My code is:

```
SELECT AUTHORS.AUTHORS_PHOTO, 
       AUTHORS.AUTHORS_ID, 
       AUTHORS.AUTHORS_NAME, 
       AUTHORS_MESSAGES.AUTHORS_RECEIVER_ID, 
       AUTHORS_MESSAGES.AUTHORS_SENDER_ID,
       AUTHORS_MESSAGES.MESSAGE_CONTENT,
       AUTHORS_MESSAGES.MESSAGE_DATE,
       AUTHORS_MESSAGES.CONVERSATION_ID,
       AUTHORS_MESSAGES.MESSAGE_STATUS
FROM AUTHORS_MESSAGES 
INNER JOIN AUTHORS 
    ON AUTHORS_MESSAGES.AUTHORS_SENDER_ID = AUTHORS.AUTHORS_ID
    OR AUTHORS_MESSAGES.AUTHORS_RECEIVER_ID = AUTHORS.AUTHORS_ID 
WHERE AUTHORS.AUTHORS_ID = 1555 
ORDER BY MESSAGE_DATE DESC;
```

Example of result:

```
AUTHORS_ID, AUTHORS_CONVERSATION
1555, 1
AUTHORS_ID, AUTHORS_CONVERSATION
1555, 1
AUTHORS_ID, AUTHORS_CONVERSATION
1555, 1
AUTHORS_ID, AUTHORS_CONVERSATION
1555, 4
```

Should result:

```
AUTHORS_ID, AUTHORS_CONVERSATION
1555, 1
AUTHORS_ID, AUTHORS_CONVERSATION
1555, 4
```

How can I show only **last** result ordering by **DATE** if it duplicate? Thank you!

Comment: You select 9 columns, but expect the result to have only 2 columns?

Comment: if i didn't get you wrong, just use max(massage_date)  group by would be fine

Comment: Does AUTHORS and AUTHOR_MESSAGES have primary key or unique key constraints ? Can you tell us how are they built ? (which columns are involved in those PK/UK)

Answer (score 0):

I am not currently in a situation to try this query...but please try and let me know

```
SELECT AUTHORS.AUTHORS_PHOTO, 
   AUTHORS.AUTHORS_ID, 
   AUTHORS.AUTHORS_NAME, 
   AUTHORS_MESSAGES.AUTHORS_RECEIVER_ID, 
   AUTHORS_MESSAGES.AUTHORS_SENDER_ID,
   AUTHORS_MESSAGES.MESSAGE_CONTENT,
   AUTHORS_MESSAGES.MESSAGE_DATE,
   AUTHORS_MESSAGES.CONVERSATION_ID,
   AUTHORS_MESSAGES.MESSAGE_STATUS
FROM (SELECT AUTHORS.AUTHORS_PHOTO, 
   AUTHORS.AUTHORS_ID, 
   AUTHORS.AUTHORS_NAME, 
   AUTHORS_MESSAGES.AUTHORS_RECEIVER_ID, 
   AUTHORS_MESSAGES.AUTHORS_SENDER_ID,
   AUTHORS_MESSAGES.MESSAGE_CONTENT,
   AUTHORS_MESSAGES.MESSAGE_DATE,
   AUTHORS_MESSAGES.CONVERSATION_ID,
   AUTHORS_MESSAGES.MESSAGE_STATUS ,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY  AUTHORS_CONVERSATION ORDER BY MESSAGE_DATE DESC) AS RowNumber FROM AUTHORS_MESSAGES 
INNER JOIN AUTHORS 
ON AUTHORS_MESSAGES.AUTHORS_SENDER_ID = AUTHORS.AUTHORS_ID
OR AUTHORS_MESSAGES.AUTHORS_RECEIVER_ID = AUTHORS.AUTHORS_ID 
WHERE AUTHORS.AUTHORS_ID = 1555 
ORDER BY MESSAGE_DATE DESC) AS a
WHERE a.RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: Erro na Linha de Comandos : 23 Coluna : 29
Relatório de erros -
Erro de SQL: ORA-00933: comando SQL não encerrado adequadamente
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to group by ID?

Example:

WHERE AUTHORS.AUTHORS_ID = 1555,
GROUP BY AUTHORS_ID;

And why dou you ORDER by a DATE if you only want the 
AUTHORS_ID and AUTHORS_CONVERSATION?

Answer (score 0):

```
; WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT 
        AUTHORS.AUTHORS_PHOTO, 
        AUTHORS.AUTHORS_ID, 
        AUTHORS.AUTHORS_NAME, 
        AUTHORS_MESSAGES.AUTHORS_RECEIVER_ID, 
        AUTHORS_MESSAGES.AUTHORS_SENDER_ID,
        AUTHORS_MESSAGES.MESSAGE_CONTENT,
        AUTHORS_MESSAGES.MESSAGE_DATE,
        AUTHORS_MESSAGES.CONVERSATION_ID,
        AUTHORS_MESSAGES.MESSAGE_STATUS,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AUTHORS_ID, CONVERSATION_ID ORDER BY MESSAGE_DATE DESC) AS RN
    FROM AUTHORS_MESSAGES 
    INNER JOIN AUTHORS 
        ON AUTHORS_MESSAGES.AUTHORS_SENDER_ID = AUTHORS.AUTHORS_ID
        OR AUTHORS_MESSAGES.AUTHORS_RECEIVER_ID = AUTHORS.AUTHORS_ID 
    WHERE AUTHORS.AUTHORS_ID = 1555 
    ORDER BY MESSAGE_DATE DESC;
) SELECT * FROM CTE 
WHERE RN = 1
```

Assuming You need to exclude duplicate rows by AUTHORS_ID, CONVERSATION_ID and order by MESSAGE_DATE. If differ then please do modify
PARTITOIN and ORDER portion

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to avoid the duplicates of some x,y,z columns then keep a group by on those columns.